# Google map group search - android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement a push notification for a specific category by using google map. For instance, if I have set reminder under BurgerKing category, so whenever I come close to any BurgerKing restaurant, a push notification will alert me about the reminder.

Any hint would help a lot.

Thank you,

Comment: What is your problem? explain more.

Comment: I want to set a reminder for a BuggerKing restaurant. So wherever I come to a BuggerKing, I will get a notification from that reminder.

Comment: Ohh that's very simple.you need to used `Proximity Alert` for this.